# Comparison between signed and unsigned warning

Tags: c

I have two variables:

```
unsigned short a,b;

/* When I compare them with a magic number like this */ 

if (a > 8U) /* all fine*/

/* But when I make the following comparison: */ 

if ((a-b) > 8U) /* warning: comparison between signed and unsigned*/

/* And when I make the following comparison: */ 

if ((a-b) > ((unsigned char)8U)) /* all fine again */
```

Do you have any ideas why I get the warning ?
Does this have anything to do with integer promotion maybe?

Comment: the warning is a perfect description of what you're doing...

Comment: I understood what the warning is about, but the reason eluded me (everything in the statement had unsigned types)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this expression `a-b`, integer promotions will apply which mean that `a` and `b` are likely to be promoted to `int` and the result of the expression will also be `int` which is why you get the warning when comparing against `8U` which has type `unsigned int`.

The promotion would only be to `unsinged int` rather than `int` if `int` couldn't hold all the values of `unsigned short` which would only happen on platforms where `int` was the same size as `short`.

When comparing against `(unsigned char)8U`, the `unsigned char` will also be promoted to `int` which is why the warning doesn't happen in this case.

Comment: But this is what puzzles me : why the cast to 'unsigned char' will result in an 'int' ?

Comment: @cilica: because an `unsigned char` will be promoted to an `int` whereas `8U` - which is already an `unsigned int` - isn't changed by integer promotions.

Answer (score 0):

(a-b) doesn't guarantee it's unsigned since b can be bigger than a.

That's why you are getting the warning

Comment: Not true. The type of the expression is not related to the actual values. If `a` and `b` where `unsigned int` then the difference would be also `unsigned int`. The real reason is because of _integer promotion_ (see the correct answer by Charles Bailey).